# Share Intent from native android app to flutter app not working when flutter app is in foreground

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I want to send data with intent from native android app to flutter app, So if flutter app is closed below code working fine to fetch intent data in main.dart file. **If flutter app is in foreground and i tries to send data from native app to flutter app nothing happens**. Is their anything else to need implement for this case?

Native app code to start flutter app

```
var intent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.flutterapp");
     intent.putString( "MapParams", jsonObj.toString())
            startActivity(intent)
```

Flutter app code

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() 
var sharedData="";
       override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
       GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            "share_channel").setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "MapParams") {
                handleIntent()
                result.success(sharedData)
                sharedData = ""
            }
        }
}
private fun handleIntent() {

            if (getIntent().hasExtra("MapParams")) {
                getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MapParams")?.let { intentData ->
                    sharedData = intentData.toString()
                }
            }
    }
```

Main.Dart file

```
Future<String> getSharedData() async {
    return await MethodChannel('share_channel')
        .invokeMethod("MapParams") ??
        "";
  }
```

Comment: I override the onNewIntent and placed same methodChannel there and its now working for me..